# Input box value vanishes when adding a new one

Tags: javascript, function, input

I'm working on a web app where I need to add a number of input boxes one after the other in order to get commands from the user. I add them using JavaScript to a div with a unique ID to each. The problem I have is once I press enter and the JavaScript function is called to add the next one, the previous input box empties out, and I don't know why.

Here is sample code:

```js
var i = 0;
add_input();

function add_input() {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<p>&gt; <input type='text' style='width:90%' id='input" + i + "' onkeypress='press_key(event, this)'></p>";
  document.getElementById('input' + i).focus();
}

function press_key(e, t) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    add_input();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='main'></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if using a framework/library is allowable for your task I highly suggest KnockoutJS for something like this.  Their tutorial covers this exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) will add the right hand value to the left hand value and then assign the resultant value to the left hand side.

For a quick example:

```
x += y;
// is equivalent to
x = x + y;
```

In your code you are basically taking the existing HTML, adding a new chunk of HTML and then assigning that new HTML to the original element replacing the existing HTML. Since the value is not set in the HTML but stored in the DOM it is lost as soon as you assign new HTML to the element (which is when the browser renders it to the DOM replacing the previous DOM).

You could use `insertNode` as mentioned above or set the HTML attribute to store the value first as the below example shows. However note that **this solution is purely to show why the values are disappearing**. Doing it this way has an issue that if any of the previous input values are changed only the original value for those inputs would be preserved.

```js
var i = 0;
add_input();

function add_input() {
  var curInput = document.getElementById('input' + i);
  if (curInput) {
    curInput.setAttribute('value', curInput.value);
  }

  ++i;
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += "<p>&gt; <input type='text' style='width:90%' id='input" + i + "' onkeypress='press_key(event, this)'></p>";
  document.getElementById('input' + i).focus();
}

function press_key(e, t) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    add_input();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='main'></div>
```

Comment: This actually worked in the sample page but didn't work in my app because of more processing done and some more page modification. I worked around it by saving `t.value` in `press_key` and using that for the `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 4):

innerHTML will override all existing content and replace them with new ones. You should create a new input element and use [`insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode) instead.

Comment: Well I use `+=` so it doesn't overwrite the previous stuff. Although perhaps with `insertNode` it wouldn't happen, it doesn't really tells me why it's happening...

Comment: @Dendory You are in fact overwriting the previous stuff. See my answer for why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` overwrites all html from the selected element including any user/javascript actions performed on the given html. Thus your input values will be erased with the new html. You are going to want to create an element and then use `appendChild`. This will maintain the state of your current html elements.

```js
       var i = 0;
function add_input()
{
i++;
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.onkeypress=press_key;
    input.id = 'input' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    
input.focus();
}
function press_key(e)
{
//`t` argument is no longer used. Use `this` instead.
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
 add_input();
}
}
```

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <script>

      </script>
     </head>
     <body onload='add_input()'>
      <div id='main'>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm getting several issues with doing it this way. First, `press_key` doesn't work anymore. It says `t is undefined`. How do I get the text for `press_key` to work? Second, I need to add the input box inside of a `p` tag which has some text in front of the input. I tried adding another `p` element, adding some `innerHTML = '&gt; '` in it and then adding the input box to it, but the `>` didn't show up..

Comment: `t` argument is no longer used. Use `this` instead. As far as the rest of your questions go, I think you may need to take a look at the [documentation for creating elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Essentially, you will need to create other elements using the `createElement` syntax and `appendChild` your `input` *onto* the newly created `p` elements.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, your other values disappear due to the inner workings of "innerHTML". In fact, when you do string.innerHTML += string it will replace the HTML for it (meaning what was there before is totally gone and is de-facto replaced with fresh new HTML).

What you want to use is probably appendChild().

With little rewriting I have managed to make your code work:

http://jsfiddle.net/gs1s0fsx/

```js
 var i = 0;

 function add_input() {
     i++;

     var main = document.getElementById('main'),
         p = document.createElement("p"),
         arrow = document.createTextNode('>'),
         el = document.createElement('input');
     el.type = "text";
     el.style = "width:90%";
     el.id = "input" + i;
     el.addEventListener("keypress", press_key);
     main.appendChild(p);
     main.appendChild(arrow);
     main.appendChild(el);
     el.focus();
 }

 function press_key(e, t) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         add_input();
     }
 }
```

```html
<a href="javascript: add_input()">add</a>

<div id='main'></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the other answer, this breaks `press_key` whenever I need to do something with `t` plus requires a major rewrite since adding input boxes is obviously not all what the app does. Instead I went with the option to save the current value and then restore that value before appending the next input box.